# ArgoCD ApplicationSet - How to preserve application and resources even when ApplicationSet is Deleted or Corrupted

Tags: argocd

I have an `ApplicationSet` which creates a few resources in Kubernetes. It is working fine. But, when I delete this `ApplicationSet`, the relevant `Application` also gets deleted from Argo, along with its resources. (I know this is expected by the ApplicationSet-Controller). But, I want to prevent this from happening.

Scenario: sometimes, when the `ApplicationSet` is corrupted, it will destroy the `Application` associated with it. The same when the `ApplicationSet` is deleted too.

I was reading this [document](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Application-Deletion/), on adding the `.syncPolicy.preserveResourcesOnDeletion` to true in the ApplicationSet, but it doesn't work as expected. This is my current sync policy:

```yaml
syncPolicy:
  automated:
    selfHeal: true
  syncOptions:
    - Validate=true
    - CreateNamespace=true
    - preserveResourcesOnDeletion=true
```

**Question**: How can I keep my `Application` safe, even when the `ApplicationSet` is deleted/corrupted?

Answer (score 4):

There are two different places you can set a sync policy:

1. on the Application resource (i.e. in `spec.template` in the ApplicationSet)
2. on the ApplicationSet resource

You're looking for the second one. Set this in your ApplicationSet resource:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
spec:
  syncPolicy:
    preserveResourcesOnDeletion: true
```

Answer (score 1):

when you install the argocd you can set the values like this:

```yaml
  applicationSet:
    args:
      policy: create-only
```

therefore Argocd will only create the application-set only once even if something happened to application set applications wont be affected by that

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the syncPolicy for that purpose should be written as

```yaml
syncPolicy:   
  preserveResourcesOnDeletion: true   
  automated:     
    selfHeal: true   
  syncOptions:     
    - Validate=true     
    - CreateNamespace=true
```

Answer (score -1):

by default ArgoCD deletion action is cascaded by default which means that all the resources created by the AppSet will be deleted.

what you need is to set the cascade option to false when you are attempting to delete the Application/ApplicationSet something similar to the below

kubectl delete ApplicationSet (NAME) --cascade=false

for more information take a look at the docs here https://argocd-applicationset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Application-Deletion/

Comment: Thank you. I know this, but I want to prevent this when `ApplicationSets` are accidentally deleted. Is there an option around the `ApplicationSet` manifest? Or in a setting in the `ApplicationSet-Controller`?